# Qt App. Deployment on Mac/XP/Vista/Windows 7: Any common access directory to put the License File?

Tags: qt, deployment, windows-7, path, windows-xp

I have to deploy a Qt Application on the following environments:

- Mac OS/X (>= Tiger 10.4 Intel Based, up to Snow Leopard 10.6.+)
- Windows XP
- Windows Vista
- Windows 7

I need a common access directory to put the License File, and I need every user of the machine to have read/write access to it - not only the administrator.

I checked many Qt functions like the following:

```
QString QDir::homePath()
QDir QDir::home ()
QString QDir::rootPath ()
QString QDir::tempPath ()
```

...but they all seem to return either user-specific or too-general paths.

Is there any Qt specific function to get a common "Applications Path"?

I 've started to think about creating my own function taking into account the OS version,
but even in this case I feel a bit lost. 
Do you know any good source to find what should be an appropriate path for each one for the OS I mentioned above?

Comment: Why do users need to be able to **write** to the license agreement?

Comment: @Cody Gray: Good question. Because I want the user (even a non-admin one) to be able to enter the license-no & activate the license (I know this is a weird approach). Another reason is that I may decide to store some hidden files/directories in this base directory for the Trial Edition of the application.

Comment: @Cody Gray: sorry, I just now realized the misunderstanding. I don't really want to store a License Agreement file but a License Registration file (containing the customer e-mail, License Serial Number, Activation Code, etc)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an answer to my own question, 
but I 'll wait to see if there is any better solutions.
(maybe there is a Qt function I missed).

I did the following hack using the QSettings class 
(@thequark: +1 for the inspiration):

```
---------------------------------------------
QString orgName = "fooOrg";
QString appName = "fooApp";
QSettings qsettings(QSettings::IniFormat, QSettings::SystemScope, orgName, appName);
QString iniFilepath = qsettings.fileName();
QString commAppPath = iniFilepath.left(iniFilepath.length() - 
                                       QString("/fooOrg/fooApp.ini").length());
---------------------------------------------
```

As you can see, I don't really use the QSettings object but
I just get its filepath to see where Qt is going to store it.

It's important to use:

- **QSettings::IniFormat**: Because we are
  interested in a file - not e.g. a
  Windows registry position
- **QSettings::SystemScope**: Because we want a machine specific and not 
  a user-specific path

The above code yields the following results for (1) iniFilepath (2) commAppPath variables and the various O/S:

**Mac Snow Leopard 10.6.7**

1. /Library/Preferences/Qt/fooOrg/fooApp.ini
2. /Library/Preferences/Qt

**Windows XP-SP3**

1. C:/Documents And Settings/All Users/Application Data/fooOrg/fooApp.ini
2. C:/Documents And Settings/All Users/Application Data

**Windows 7 (64) and Windows Vista SP2**

1. C:/ProgramData/fooOrg/fooApp.ini
2. C:/ProgramData

Although it's a hack, I think it's a good solution 
involving only internal Qt calls and not using any O/S specific functions.

If you have any better idea... please let me know.

**EDIT - PS:** In Mac OS-X the directory "/Library/Preferences" is not writable for a non-admin user. I finally used the directory "/Users/Shared".

Comment: Hmm. Those look like the right paths to use on Windows. The only thing to be careful of is hard-coding the path separator into your code. I believe the Windows shell accepts a forward slash most places, but the backslash is the official path separator, and even that's not guaranteed to be constant across all platforms. I imagine Qt provides some kind of `pathSeparator` property that you can use instead?

Comment: @Cody Gray: No there is no problem with the '/' on Qt even when you use it on a windows application. Actually the official documentation instructs you to use '/' everywhere and the Qt QFile & QDir classes will convert it internally to the appropriate separator for the target OS. The only exception is when you want to make a native Windows API call where you can use the QDir::toNativeSeparators() function.

Answer (score 2):

I am a n00b in Qt too so I am not sure if this is the best option but how about using [`QSettings`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qsettings.html) to get the path to license file from a settings/configuration file. This file with proper values should be created by the installer. Installer can take care of using some default values specific to the OS or even ask user at the time of installation, so you application is independent of the OS. `QSettings` has persistence so you don't have to bother about reading, writing on to a file.

Comment: Thank you for the answer (I feel like a newbie too, after one year in Qt). In fact I discovered QSettings just 1 hour ago while I have already created  my own format to save the application settings. Regarding my initial question: I want to have full control in the Application itself, therefore I don't want to split the logic between the App. and Installer (the installer in Mac OS/X can be a simple drag and drop). Moreover the question remains: How the installer will discover this O/S specific, "common-application" path and which are the candidate locations on each O/S?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [QDesktopServices::storageLocation](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qdesktopservices.html#storageLocation).

QDesktopServices::DataLocation enum seems appropriate.

Comment: I already used this to store user specific data. It returns a user-specific path like this one (on Windows 7): c:\Users\<user-name>\AppData\Local\<app-name> while I actually need a non-user-specific path.

Answer (score 1):

For Windows 2000 and higher, this folder is known as [CSIDL_COMMON_APPDATA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762494.aspx#CSIDL_COMMON_APPDATA).